# Quick Integration Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was given the following question:

[image]

And I've tried to tackle it, but it's a bit confusing to me. I thought I'd flip the bounds on the integral equation that equals $12$ and solve for the second integral equation that they're looking for, but none of the answers are lining up with where this process would put me. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1.$$\begin{align}\int_{10}^{-1}g(x)\,dx &= -\int_{-1}^{10}g(x)\,dx\\
&=-\int_{-1}^{3}g(x)\,dx-\int_{3}^{10}g(x)\,dx\end{align}$$

2. $$\int(2g(x)+4)\,dx = 2\int g(x)\,dx + \int4\,dx$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\int_{-1}^{3}g(x) dx+\int_{10}^{-1}g(x) dx=\int_{10}^{3}g(x)dx=-\int_{3}^{10}g(x)dx$$
and you can separate the first integral to find $\int_{-1}^{3}g(x) dx.$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{3}{(2g(x) + 4)dx} &= 2\int_{-1}^{3}{g(x)dx} + \int_{-1}^{3}{4dx} \\
                             &= 2\int_{-1}^{3}{g(x)dx} + 16 \\
                             &= 22
\end{align*}

Rearranging the last equation gives

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{3}{g(x)dx} = 3
\end{align*}

With that in mind, you can solve the original problem by expressing the integral you want to solve for in terms of the other two integrals.

\begin{align*}
\int_{3}^{10}{g(x)dx} &= \int_{-1}^{10}{g(x)dx} - \int_{-1}^{3}{g(x)dx} \\
&= -\int_{10}^{-1}{g(x)dx} - \int_{-1}^{3}{g(x)dx} \\
&= -12 - 3 \\
&= -15
\end{align*}

Comment: I think I'm understanding what you're saying, so when applying this process to the problem, did you get the answer to be $9$?

Comment: I believe the 12 has to be negative since the bounds of integration are switched. I've updated the answer so you can compare it with yours.